# "AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'" while using the function history to extract stock information

Tags: python, data-science, ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I'm trying to extract information of the Tesla stock but, I always get the error while coding it. Here's the code so far:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

def make_graph(stock_data, revenue_data, stock):

    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, subplot_titles=("Historical Share Price", "Historical Revenue"), vertical_spacing = .3)
    stock_data_specific = stock_data[stock_data.Date <= '2021--06-14']
    revenue_data_specific = revenue_data[revenue_data.Date <= '2021-04-30']
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(stock_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=stock_data_specific.Close.astype("float"), name="Share Price"), row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(revenue_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=revenue_data_specific.Revenue.astype("float"), name="Revenue"), row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Price ($US)", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Revenue ($US Millions)", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False,
    height= 900,
    title= stock,
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
    fig.show()

Tesla= yf.Ticker('TSLA')
tesla_database= Tesla.history(period= "max")
```

In the tesla_database part is where the following error comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    tesla_database= Tesla.history(period= "max")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/base.py", line 295, in history
    df.index = df.index.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert(
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'
```

How can I fix this? According to the IBM Watson Course in Coursera, this is the correct answer but I get this error all the time. Can someone correct it, please?

Comment: is `'2021--06-14'` correct? the other date `'2021-04-30'` has one `-` less.

Comment: @ack This is the code I got in the notebook

Comment: you can probably remove the extra `-` from the code

Comment: @PrakashDahal I did remove the extra code but I received the same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with pandas 1.4.1 For me reverting back to a previous pandas version solved the problem:

Try this on command line:

```
pip install pandas==1.2.2
```

Try this from whithin Jupyter Board:

```
!pip install pandas==1.2.2
```